# WooCommerce and Wordpress PHP memory_limit problem

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have three WooCommerce based shops installed on my server, basically they are identical shops using the same plugins and themes and the assortment is almost identical (product presentation also).

Each store database has less than 100MB.

In one case I have memory problem for PHP scripts, while memory_limit is set to 256M one store still has memory problems. Others work ok.

```
[01-May-2020 22:23:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14069080 bytes) in /home/shop1/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2951
[01-May-2020 22:33:22 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10489856 bytes) in /home/shop1/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 708
```

I can raise the memory_limit to e.g. 384M and the problem disappears. But why does such a script require more than 256MB and the other two do not? Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a memory leak or from what I can understand if you have set 256M and each one is 100MB that means you only have space for 2 of them and hence the 3rd one is running out of ram.

Make sure that on your php.ini you put more ram and then assign enough ram to each webstore that does not surpass your overall amount.

Your php.ini is most likely taking over and setting the overall RAM rather than the ram PER instance. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: No, it's not a memory leak.
Besides, if there was a memory deficit, every store would have a problem with that.

Evidently this one shop needs a bigger limit - if memory_limit is set to 384M the problem disappears. If it was a memory leak, then when setting the limit to 384M this problem would also occur.